# SQLite and fractional seconds comparison in datetime

Tags: sqlite

So, I have a following SQLite query:

```
SELECT datetime('2013-10-07 08:23:19.111') = datetime('2013-10-07 08:23:19.222')
```

To my surprise the result that I get is ... 1 (true). No matter what values I put after the dot, it is always true when fractional values are different.

[According to docs](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html):

> In formats 4, 7, and 10, the fractional seconds value SS.SSS can have one or more digits following the decimal point. Exactly three digits are shown in the examples because only the first three digits are significant to the result, but the input string can have fewer or more than three digits and the date/time functions will still operate correctly.

Is there some sort of mistake or is there something I don't understand?

Answer (score 3):

The page you linked to says:

> The datetime() function returns "YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS".

If you know that your values already are exactly in the correct format, just compare the strings directly. Otherwise, replace datetime() with strftime() with `%f` to convert the values into the format you want.

Comment: Indeed, that's correct. Worth mentioning is that only 3 digits are significant when operating on datetime strings. So query:

`SELECT strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%f', '2013-10-07 08:23:19.111') = strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%f', '2013-10-07 08:23:19.111001')`

will return ... 1 (true)